# Load modules with require.js

Tags: javascript

```
define("file2",['file1'],function(){console.log('World')})
```

file2.js

```
var oli={name:boo.joni};
```

file1.js

```
var boo={joni:100};
```

I want to included the file "file2", before it needs to be loaded "file1". Once all scripts must call callbacks. It does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need javascript loader with dependencies, take a look here for example:

http://www.dustindiaz.com/scriptjs

There are also some answers here:
[JavaScript dependency management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202606/javascript-dependency-management)
[How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-javascript-file-inside-javascript-file)
[Javascript dependency solution with arbitrary ordered includes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315755/javascript-dependency-solution-with-arbitrary-ordered-includes)